# linux + LVM + extent small disk by add another disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, lvm, disk

we have Linux machine redhat 7.2 LVM disk

disk -sdd with only 2G

we want to extend the size of **/data** to 20G by adding another disk - sde

```
/dev/sdd            2.0G  9.2M  1.9G   1% /data
```

expected results

```
/dev/sdd            20.0G  9.2M  1.9G   1% /data
```

what is the procedure that explain how to add another disk and join the new disk size to "sdd" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like your `/dev/sdd` is a member of LVM Group.
You cannot just extend your device. Expected result is not able to be done.

By the subject, I can assume, you would like to use LVM to extend `/dev/sdd` and keep your data from `/dev/sdd` on `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde` at `/data` mount-point.

If so, the procedure looks like that:

- **Do reliable the backup** of `/data`.
- Create *physical-volume* from `/dev/sdd`. (It will wipe-out your data from `/dev/sdd`)
- Create *physical-volume* from `/dev/sde` (It will wipe-out your data from `/dev/sde`)
- Create *volume-group* that consists of two *PVs*: `/dev/sdd` and `/dev/sde`.
- Create linear *logical-volume*, create filesystem on it, mount it on `/data`.
- Restore your backup.

References:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvm

Comment: thank you , can you please described how to Create physical-volume , Create volume-group , Create linear logical-volume ( or just explain by commands the steps ,

Comment: Have a look at `pvcreate` `vgcreate` `lvcreate` commands.

Comment: do we need to umount the mount point from sdd when we do pvcreate>